# rosinstall inifinite recursion problem

Tags: rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using rosinstall-0.5.16. I am troubled by a infinite recursion when calling rosinstall. (in python script /usr/local/bin/rosinstall line 518). I am puzzled by this behaviour that appeared only recently.

My rosinstall config file (stripped down to the offending lines) is

```
  - other: {local-name: /opt/ros/diamondback/ros}
  - other: {local-name: /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks}
```

and I believe, I am doing something wrong here. I get the following error when calling

```
$ rosinstall . my.rosinstall
  [...]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/rosinstall-0.5.16-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 202, in __init__
    self.load_yaml(self.source, self.source_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/rosinstall-0.5.16-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 229, in load_yaml
    child_config = Config(rosinstall.helpers.get_yaml_from_uri(rosinstall_uri), local_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/rosinstall-0.5.16-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 202, in __init__
    self.load_yaml(self.source, self.source_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/rosinstall-0.5.16-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 229, in load_yaml
    child_config = Config(rosinstall.helpers.get_yaml_from_uri(rosinstall_uri), local_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/rosinstall-0.5.16-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 202, in __init__
    self.load_yaml(self.source, self.source_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/rosinstall-0.5.16-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 229, in load_yaml
    child_config = Config(rosinstall.helpers.get_yaml_from_uri(rosinstall_uri), local_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/rosinstall-0.5.16-py2.6.egg/rosinstall/helpers.py", line 63, in get_yaml_from_uri
    y = yaml.load(f);
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 58, in load
    return loader.get_single_data()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 42, in get_single_data
    node = self.get_single_node()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 36, in get_single_node
    document = self.compose_document()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 55, in compose_document
    node = self.compose_node(None, None)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 82, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_sequence_node(anchor)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 111, in compose_sequence_node
    node.value.append(self.compose_node(node, index))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 133, in compose_mapping_node
    item_value = self.compose_node(node, item_key)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 64, in compose_node
    if self.check_event(AliasEvent):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 93, in check_event
    self.current_event = self.state()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 444, in parse_block_mapping_value
    if not self.check_token(KeyToken, ValueToken, BlockEndToken):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 116, in check_token
    self.fetch_more_tokens()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 252, in fetch_more_tokens
    return self.fetch_plain()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 672, in fetch_plain
    self.save_possible_simple_key()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 310, in save_possible_simple_key
    self.index, self.line, self.column, self.get_mark())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/yaml/reader.py", line 155, in get_mark
    None, None)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I want the diamondback stacks to be included in the environment created by rosinstall. I was following the Wiki instructions at http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosinstall#Other_Mode. Any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10250/rosinstall-inifinite-recursion-problem/) by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 960 on 2011-06-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's an [open ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3316)  with this symptom.  It's caused by a .rosinstall in the parent directory.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your rosinstall file looks good. Are you, by chance, executing `rosinstall . my.rosinstall` in a subdirectory of /opt/ros/diamondback? Try the following:

```
mkdir $HOME/ros
rosinstall $HOME/ros my.rosinstall
```

You need to make sure that rosinstall doesn't find a file named .rosinstall from the directory you are calling rosinstall on up to your filesystem root.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-06-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on 2011-06-14**:
Nope, I never modify /opt/ros/diamondback. The hint with the .rosinstall file in the parent did the trick.